# How to align an image left in Header

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm designing a jQuery Mobile site, and I want an image as a header, but when I insert an image, the image is center aligned, and cut off. How can I set the image to be left aligned to show everything?

My coding:

```
<div data-role="header">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <h1><img src="/images/HomePage.jpg" width="202" height="104" style=" overflow:visible; float:left" align="left"/></h1>
    </div>
```

Please help me! :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a class to the `div` with background-image.

Like this...

HTML

```
<div data-role="header" class="header"></div>
```

CSS

```
.header {
  background-image:url("../images/HomePage.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code, use ui-btn-icon-left built in class for aligning to left you can adjust padding and margin.

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
           <img src="images/logo.png" width="202" height="104" class="ui-btn-icon-left" />
        </div>
```